# Node.js server don't show image

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, invisible

I am with a problem over here, I am using node.js framework to handle the requests to my index.html.
The index.html file has some images, but its not appearing for my users! 
I am reading both files, index.html and the .png . 
Can you guys help me?
Here is my server.js:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
var fs = require('fs')

app.listen(4000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {

      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.end(data);

  });


  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/blackq.png', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {

      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.end(data);

  });


}
```

THanks alot in advance!

Comment: The request for the html and the png will be **two separate requests**. All your code does is return `index.html` for every single request to the server, regardless of the file being requested.

Comment: but I want to enable the request of index.html containing the image files, how should I do ? thanks for u reply

Comment: You'll need to look at `req` ([documentation here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)) to determine which URL the browser asked for, so you know which file to send back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brandon, would be appreciated with few more help. I need to accept an answer :)
Thanks ;)
the request has the attribute request.url right? and I need to check if is for the image or for the html ? how can I compare it? thanks !

Comment: Your primary concern here is HTTP Routing. Take a look at that concept and there are a few node.js libraries that can help you with this, e.g. https://github.com/flatiron/director#http-routing

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution just for proof of concept could go like this:

In your html file, make sure you have the img tab done right.

`<img src="/your_image.jpg" alt="your_image" style="width:304px;height:228px;">`

In your node.js server file, adding

```
  if (req.url == "/index.html") {
  //res.end your html file
  return;
  }

  //to display image
  if (req.url == "/your_image.jpg") {

     var img = fs.readFileSync('./your_image.jpg');
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
     res.end(img, 'binary');

     return;

  }
```